# Error: AnchorError: AnchorError caused by account: base_account. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, account, account-data

I wrote a Solana Program with two functions, one for the initialization of an account and a second to upload data to the account. While testing on localhost it was working fine, but when I uploaded it to Devnet I get the following error:

```
Error: AnchorError: AnchorError caused by account: base_account. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.
      at AnchorError.parse (C:\Development\SmartHealth\smarthealth_js\node_modules\@project-serum\anchor\dist\cjs\error.js:138:20)
      at translateError (C:\Development\SmartHealth\smarthealth_js\node_modules\@project-serum\anchor\dist\cjs\error.js:224:37)
      at Object.rpc [as uploadRecord] (C:\Development\SmartHealth\smarthealth_js\node_modules\@project-serum\anchor\dist\cjs\program\namespace\rpc.js:18:53)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async uploadToSolana (file:///C:/Development/SmartHealth/smarthealth_js/index.js:69:22)
      at async file:///C:/Development/SmartHealth/smarthealth_js/index.js:131:28
```

**The error comes up only when I try to upload the data and sometimes it doesn't come up at all and the data gets uploaded successfully to the account. I am not sure why I am getting this error sometimes. Can someone please tell me what is the problem?**

Below is the JS code through which I am calling the Solana program functions:

```
const tx = await program.rpc.initialize({
        accounts:{
            baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
            user:provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [baseAccount]
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
        return {"Error":err}
    });

console.log('New Base Account Generated: ',baseAccount.publicKey.toString());
console.log("Transaction Signature: ",tx);

const timestamp = new Date().toUTCString()
    const uploadTx = await program.rpc.uploadRecord(pid,did,title,file_id,timestamp,{
        accounts: {
            baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
            user:provider.wallet.publicKey,
        },
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
        return {"Error":err}
    });
```

I have even tried keeping the pid,did, title,file_id values the same but still I get the error sometimes. Even the account gets generated as I get the transaction signature for that on the console but data doesn't get uploaded.

Comment: Can you add more context by sharing the program this error means that you are trying to use an account that has not been created yet

Comment: @Pratik.js Hey, Thank You but actually the code started working after I put a delay between the initialization and upload function calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running these one after the other or adding a delay between them, but both instructions into the same transaction. E.g.:

```
  let tx = new Transaction();
  tx.add(await program.methods.initialize(....).instruction());
  tx.add(await program.methods.uploadRecord(....).instruction());
  await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [baseAccount]);
```

This way the account is always created when you go to call upload, because it will be created earlier within the same tx.

Comment: I changed my code to the way you said but I get the following error:

throw new Error(`provided too many arguments ${args} to instruction ${idlIx === null || idlIx === void 0 ? void 0 : idlIx.name} expecting: ${(_b = (_a = idlIx.args) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.map((a) => a.name)) !== null && _b !== void 0 ? _b : []}`);
                  ^

Error: provided too many arguments [object Object],[object Object] to instruction initialize expecting:
    at splitArgsAndCtx

Comment: Code: 
`let tx = new Transaction();
    tx.add(await program.methods.initialize({
        accounts:{
            baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
            user:provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        }
    }).instruction());
    tx.add(await program.methods.uploadRecord(pid,did,title,file_id,timestamp,{
            accounts: {
                baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
                user:provider.wallet.publicKey,
            }

    }).instruction());

    await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [baseAccount]);`

Comment: Replace the .... in each `methods.whatever` with your instruction args. E.g. `methods.initialize(ARG1, ARG2, ARG2).accounts({someacc: whatever})`

Comment: Yeah I was doing it wrong, Thank You, it worked